# Eclipse and Automatic Screenshots

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot, android-screen

I am using eclipse Indigo for Android Development.
This might sound a little crazy , but
Is there any feature in eclipse that will automatically take screenshots of every screen while the app is running? 
Or does this need to be done programatically?
Actually what I want is, I need screen shots of all the screens in my app.
And I want to avoid taking them manually using DDMS perspective.

Any info would be helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any feature in eclipse that will automatically take
>   screenshots of every screen while the app is running?

Yes, You can take a screenshot if you

> open the Android view "devices" (under Window --> Show View -->
>   Other... --> Android --> Devices).  Click on the device or emulator
>   you want to take a screen shot of, then click the "Screen Capture"
>   button (it looks like a little picture, and it should be next to a
>   stop sign button).  Occasionally the device won't immediately load the
>   picture; sometimes you have to close/reopen the screen capture window.

**This is equivalent to taking a picture via DDMS**, but you can do it in Eclipse instead of opening another application.

> does this need to be done programatically?

**Yes**, you can also do it like it as Below Code Suggests.

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you need to access use something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I found and it works. 
http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/08/android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast/